# Perl module to find out whether a word is a verb/noun/adjective/article/preposition

Tags: perl, nlp

I have a list of words and I want to group them into different groups depending on whether they are verbs/adjectives/nouns/etc. So, basically I am looking for a Perl module which tells whether a word is verb/noun etc.

I googled but couldn't find what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Try searching http://metacpan.org instead of Google for Perl modules.

Comment: Also, your question has no definite, singular answer. Words in English are often used as several different parts of speech, determined by how they are used in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Lingua::EN:: namespace in CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=lingua%3a%3aen&mode=all). Specifically, [Link Grammar](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/) and perhaps [Lingua::EN::Tagger](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aTagger) can help you. Also WordNet provides that kind of information and you can query it [using this perl module](http://qwone.com/~jason/WordNet/).

Answer (score 1):

[Lingua::EN::Tagger](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aTagger), [Lingua::EN::Semtags::Engine](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aSemtags%3a%3aEngine), [Lingua::EN::NamedEntity](http://p3rl.org/Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aNamedEntity)

Comment: You can’t do good POS assignment without an actual parse. If you have loose words, the best you can do is a trivial dictionary lookup, which isn’t very satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

follow code perl help you to find all this thing in your text file in your folder only give the path of directory and it will process all file at once and save result in report.txt file strong text

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/perl

# for loop execution



# Perl Program to calculate Factorial
sub fact
{

# Retriving the first argument
# passed with function calling
my $x = $_[0];
my @names = @{$_[1]};
my $length = $_[2];

# checking if that value is 0 or 1
if ($x < $length)
{
#print @names[$x],"\n";

 use Lingua::EN::Fathom;
 my $text = Lingua::EN::Fathom->new();

 # Analyse contents of a text file
 $dirlocation="./2015/";
 $path =$dirlocation.$names[$x];

 $text->analyse_file($path); # Analyse contents of a text file

 $accumulate = 1;
 # Analyse contents of a text string
 $text->analyse_block($text_string,$accumulate);
  # TO Do, remove repetition

 $num_chars             = $text->num_chars;
 $num_words             = $text->num_words;
 $percent_complex_words = $text->percent_complex_words;
 $num_sentences         = $text->num_sentences;
 $num_text_lines        = $text->num_text_lines;
 $num_blank_lines       = $text->num_blank_lines;
 $num_paragraphs        = $text->num_paragraphs;
 $syllables_per_word    = $text->syllables_per_word;
 $words_per_sentence    = $text->words_per_sentence;

# comment needed
 %words = $text->unique_words;
 foreach $word ( sort keys %words )
 {
#   print("$words{$word} :$word\n");
 }

 $fog     = $text->fog;
 $flesch  = $text->flesch;
 $kincaid = $text->kincaid;
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use 5.010;

    my $filename = 'report.txt';
    open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    say $fh $text->report;
    close $fh;
    say 'done';
    print($text->report);

    $x = $x+1;
    fact($x,\@names,$length);
}

# Recursively calling function with the next value
# which is one less than current one
else
{
    done();
}
}

# Driver Code
$a = 0;
@names = ("John Paul", "Lisa", "Kumar","touqeer");
opendir DIR1, "./2015" or die "cannot open dir: $!";
my @default_files= grep { ! /^\.\.?$/ } readdir  DIR1;
$length = scalar @default_files;
print $length;
# Function call and printing result after return
fact($a,\@default_files,$length);

sub done
{
    print "Done!";
}
```